# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, socket-timeout-exception

I hava a working `xmlparser` 
But unfortunately i get an error when i'm on mobile data.
The problem doesn't occur on Wi-Fi and the page is available at any time.
What do i do wrong?
I've the permission for Internet.

**Stack trace**:

```
    05-14 21:26:35.628: W/System.err(17691): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to buie.vlsolutions.nl/185.10.98.4 (port 80) after 15000ms
    05-14 21:26:35.633: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
    05-14 21:26:35.633: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    05-14 21:26:35.633: W/System.err(17691):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    05-14 21:26:35.633: W/System.err(17691):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    05-14 21:26:35.633: W/System.err(17691):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    05-14 21:26:35.633: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at nl.vlsolutions.buienl.MainActivity.downloadUrl(MainActivity.java:475)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at nl.vlsolutions.buienl.MainActivity.loadXmlFromNetwork(MainActivity.java:342)
    05-14 21:26:35.638: W/System.err(17691):    at nl.vlsolutions.buienl.MainActivity.access$2(MainActivity.java:334)
    05-14 21:26:35.643: W/System.err(17691):    at nl.vlsolutions.buienl.MainActivity$DownloadXmlTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:307)
    05-14 21:26:35.643: W/System.err(17691):    at nl.vlsolutions.buienl.MainActivity$DownloadXmlTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    05-14 21:26:35.643: W/System.err(17691):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    05-14 21:26:35.643: W/System.err(17691):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    05-14 21:26:35.643: W/System.err(17691):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    05-14 21:26:35.643: W/System.err(17691):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    05-14 21:26:35.643: W/System.err(17691):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    05-14 21:26:35.643: W/System.err(17691):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    05-14 21:26:35.648: W/System.err(17691):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**Function downloadUrl**:

```
private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Starts the query
    conn.connect();     // Line 475
    return conn.getInputStream();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out there was an problem with the DNS Server from my data provider. Because my server just changed IP-addresses and the DNS Server was not yet updated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to increase the connection time out? maybe your mobile data connection is too slow in contrary to your wifi. use try and catch and post the exception here, I think it'll be more helpful than the logcat in this case.

Comment: I don't have a slow connection however when i try to access the URL in my browser it's showing an error too. So i don't know where to search now because the server is always available.